# Компиляция проекта Еclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Как компилировать проект Еclipse, чтобы его можно было открыть на другом ПК?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду скомпилировать запускаемый .jar файл? Если да, то Пкм по `проект -> Export -> Java -> Runnable JAR file`.